# Force close when already scan

Tags: android

i want to scan qr code with android studio but when i scan the qr code its always force close the a apk
here is the code for the result :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCodeScanner = new CodeScanner(this, scannerView);
        mCodeScanner.setDecodeCallback(new DecodeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDecoded(@NonNull final Result result) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String message = "result :\n" + result.getText();
                        showAlertDialog(message);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        checkCameraPermission();
    }
```

I don't get any error message when running the apk and still don't know what causes it

Comment: Please post full *crash log* here.

Comment: please check the logcat and post the error message here